# Changing div postion depending on page scroll

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the following code below that changes a div's position to fixed once an element scrollTop is greater than a number. I am trying to either amend this script or find a different solution so that the div will scroll between a range and STOP scrolling at some point ( so the div doesn't go off the page or overlap with footer elements.

I don't know if the right way is to say that IF scrollTop is greater than 150 then position=fixed, and if it's greater than 600 then position goes back to absolute, or if there's a better way, like distance from the bottom...

AND I use MooTools, not jQuery. I know there are a few jQuery options / plugins that do this. Thanks in advance!

```
window.onscroll = function()
{
    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) { // IE 6 doesnt implement position fixed nicely...     
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
            $('tabber').style.position = 'fixed';
            $('tabber').style.top = '0';

        } else {

            $('tabber').style.position = 'absolute'; 
            $('tabber').style.top = 'auto';


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you don't set the div's position to fixed and the properties left and top as you need?

Comment: he is doing it because ie6 cant do fixed.

Comment: Yah, also I'm looking for the effect where a div that is halfway down the page is stationary as the viewer scrolls the page, until that div hits the top of the window, and then it stays visible at the top of the window rather than scroll off the top.

Comment: THe script above achieves this, the problem is I need the div to stop being fixed once it reaches a certain point. So the effect I can't seem to accomplish is "Stop being fixed at HEIGHT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script above is wrong on many levels.

don't use `window.onscroll` but `window.addEvent("scroll", function() {})`;

cache selectors. using `$("tabber")` 3 times on each scroll when the element does not change is expensive.

just do `var tabber = $("tabber")` and reference that.

you don't need to do

```
$("tabber").style.position  = ... 
$("tabber").style.top  = ...
```

do:

```
tabber.setStyles({
    position: "fixed",
    top: 12123,
    right: 24
});
```

There are mootools plugins for this, eg scrollSpy by David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

it can allow you to set scripted events upon reaching various scrolling destinations or events, look at the examples.

or you could just write it yourself, eg, this took me 15 mins to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/u9J2X/ (watch http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/u9J2X/show/) - it stops being fixed when it reaches to 20 px of the footer. and then goes back to fixed if scrolling up again.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar, I'm going to check out your demo. I've use scrollspy to show and hide some divs based on position, so I'll try something with that as well.